# Is it common to say "that [month] night"?

Tags: expressions, sentence

I know it's common to say:

> I was in my apartment that Wednesday night, lights off, curtains
>   drawn, shopping on the Internet.

How about?

> I was in my apartment that January night, lights off, curtains drawn,
>   shopping on the Internet.

Comment: Yes, that is idiomatic. Also "on that winter|summer|autumn|spring night".

Comment: It's only appropriate to use ***that*** if the preceding context has already explicitly or implicitly identified the *particular* Wednesday or January night you're talking about. Absent that context, it's meaningless to ask whether the form is valid/common.

Comment: General reference: 300 000 Google hits for "that January night", with most of the first ones relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, the phrase "that [month] night" is common.